# API 2.3 GoogleCloudMessaging get only registration event

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The code is very simple and perfectly works on API >= 3.0, but if I started at API 2.3 I'm getting the problem - Google send only registration events:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { 

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {             
            //sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());    

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {             
            //sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            // we are here if API >= 3.0

        }
        else if (isRegistrationIntent(intent)) {

            // WE ARE HERE IF API 2.3 <----- BUG
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Registration is successful. But after that, my Sony Хperia (API 2.3) get only the registration's events: from another device sent GCM-message, but Xperia receive a notification of registration. Magic; (

Does anyone know the possible causes?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fenix14"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="DVA" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 

<!-- GCM settings  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.fenix14.utils.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.fenix14.utils.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- /GCM settings  -->



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="com.fenix14.utils.FenixApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FenixActionBarTheme" >


    <!-- GCM settings  -->

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.fenix14.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />                
            <category android:name="com.fenix14.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.fenix14.gcm.GcmIntentService" />     

    <!-- /GCM settings  -->   





    <activity                      
        android:name="com.fenix14.entry.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FenixActionBar.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest has many inconsistencies :

```
package="com.fenix14"

<permission android:name="com.fenix14.utils.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.fenix14.utils.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.fenix14.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />                
        <category android:name="com.fenix14.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You should use the same package name in all the GCM relevant places, so it should be :

```
package="com.fenix14"

<permission android:name="com.fenix14.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.fenix14.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.fenix14.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />                
        <category android:name="com.fenix14" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: @user3534709 I'm glad I could help. If the question is answered, please accept the answer.