# GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived not called

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get a msg to my app from a server.
I have this server url wich sends msg to all users:
https://taub-prayer-ramym.c9.io/send?message=123

my app's token is registered in the server... but I have a problem that the onMessageReceived() method from my GcmListenerService implementation isn't called.

my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.atheel.prayer" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.atheel.prayer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.atheel.prayer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.atheel.prayer.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.atheel.prayer.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.example.atheel.prayer.RegistrationIntentService"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EmptyStatus"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_empty_status" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UnEmpty"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_un_empty" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my myGCMListener :

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
    File notificationsFile;
    private String sessionForAppClosed;

    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Message Received!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.print("***************Message Received!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

anyone can think why its not working?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you already read the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) for GCM support. I also suggest you to read [this](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/) article.

Compared to my GCM code, you are missing the line

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION"/>
```

from class GcmReceiver. I also don't see meta tag about the gcm version:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Third thing that I do differently is the specification of permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <permission
    android:name="your.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

I also remember that on some networks the gcm simply do not work. It's a weird thing, but you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571576/which-port-and-protocol-does-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-use).

Edit: since the issue is still not resolved, I add my working code for receiving GCM below. Note that I suppose that the app is successfully registered in google services, firewall is not blocked and the app server successfully send the message to google servers:
GcmBroadcastReceiver - for receiving the CGM messages

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

This component calls following service

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public GcmIntentService() {
    super(App.getStr(R.string.gcm_sender_id)); // this integer is provided when registering the application 
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // here you can do your work
            }
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

}

PS: note that my solution is heavily inspired by other solutions on the internet, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105255/api-2-3-googlecloudmessaging-get-only-registration-event)

---

Comment: thank you. 
1) the missing line supposed to be in the receiver or service?
2) what you type instead of signature ?

Comment: the missing line is in receiver and "signature" is not a placeholder, it should be as it is: "signature". Check it here http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html
PS: the only placeholder in the code given is your.package - this should be your base package, which should be com.example.atheel.prayer

Comment: I posted an edit. If the problem still preserves, feel free to contact me via my website martinvano.sk . I am sure we can fix it somehow.

Comment: @vanomart i think you're still on the old APIs